# Juntar busqueda de Mongo y Busqueda de Postgres por Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, mongodb, mongoose, sequelize.js

requiero su ayuda para algo que no he hecho antes y se me requiere urgente laboralmente.

Se requiere hacer un reporte según se encuentra la información en base de datos en Postgres. Para lo cual se realiza la búsqueda a postgres que me regresa el siguiente arreglo:

```
data = await DB.sequelize.query(querys.get_ges_dav(schemaName,[req.query.fecha_inicial,req.query.fecha_final],req.query.unidad))
data = data[0] || []
```

Donde me queda toda la query realizada en postgres en la variable data.

En este punto se requiere modificar un campo de esta variable "data", para lo cual debo actualizarlo con un campo que se encuentra en Mongo, por lo cual hacer un ciclo para recorrer uno a uno los registros de "data" y hacer una búsqueda a mongo, actualizar en "data" lo recibido y seguir con el siguiente; sería algo muy poco eficiente.

Creo que se debería hacer una búsqueda general en mongo para traer el campo requerido y quedaría algo como "data2", y luego hacer esa actualización del campo en "data".

El dilema es el siguiente: Es un reporte financiero y la variable data tiene dentro de sus campos el número de documento del cliente, pero se requiere el tipo de documento (DNI, Pasaporte...) y al momento de que se haga el registro, esos dos campos no se guardan juntos, sino que el número de documento se guarda en Postgres y el tipo se guarda en mongo. Dentro del reporte actual que tiene "data" puse el capo de tipo de documento con valor defecto "DNI", pero se requiere hacer esa actualización.

Ejemplo al traer la búsqueda de postgres los campos vienen en este orden:
"id, tipo_doc, doc, ........", esto queda en la variable "data". El campo tipo_doc se trae con valor por defecto "DNI", pero se requiere actualizar según la info que se trae de Mongo.

Es la primera vez que me encuentro con esta situación, de verdad agradecería mucho su colaboración, guía o ayuda.

Datos de mongo:
Base de datos: cbpo_davivienda
Colección: asignaciones
Campo: TIPOID

---

Actualización 1:

Lo mismo pensé yo que la búsqueda de postgres me regresa un JSON pero no lo hace hasta el momento viene de la siguiente manera(No se porque, en la busqueda jamás se especifico eso):

```
[,
  [,
    {,
      codigo: 'LL  ',,
      tipo_id: '99',,
      deudor_id: '000000000179058',,
      fecha_gestion: '20210708',,
      hora_gestion: '165455',,
      hora_generacion: '000000;',
    },,
    {,
      codigo: 'LL  ',,
      tipo_id: '99',,
      deudor_id: '000000000437190',,
      fecha_gestion: '20210708',,
      hora_generacion: '000000;',
    },,
  ],
]
```

Comment: Según lo entiendo, en tu variable `data` (que es el resultado de una consulta a Postgre) tienes los valores correspondientes al *documento de identificación* (sea pasaporte, DNI, u otro), y en MongoDB se almacena el tipo de documento. Lo que no me queda claro es ¿bajo qué clave se almacena ese tipo, y qué consulta sería necesaria para ubicar esa información en MongoDB?.

Comment: Por otro lado, si en Postgre almacenas el número del documento, y en Mongo el tipo de documento, ¿de qué forman se relacionan ambos datos? Es decir, ¿existe algún campo discriminante en ambos registros que los vinculen?

Comment: @MauricioContreras Sucede exactamente como tu lo mencionas. El mismo único dato que esta en ambos lados es el valor del documento, que sería la manera para poder enlazarlos.

La consulta que necesitaría es traer los  tipos de documento correspondientes a todos los clientes y en nodejs (no se como), actualizar los "DNI" que tiene "data" por defecto, al que le corresponde.

Comment: ¿Cómo se llaman los campos y la colección donde se almacenan los datos en MongoDB? Añade eso a tu pregunta, mientras veré de prepararte una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Te agradezco mucho tu ayuda ya esta actualizada la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como comentas en tu pregunta, realizar un ciclo `for` para la búsqueda de cada documento en MongoDB no es nada eficiente. Suponiendo que la data resultante de la consulta a Postgre se tenga de la siguiente manera:

```js
// data:
[
    {
        id: <valor>,
        tipo_doc: 'DNI', // <- valor dado por defecto
        doc: <valor>
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

Y tomando en cuenta que el valor del campo `doc` es a su vez persistido en la base de datos, podrías realizar una sola operación de consulta (sin necesidad de usar un bucle `for` por cada documento de `data`).

Para ello te puedes apoyar en el operador de consultas: [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/), que recibe como argumento una lista de valores y devuelve todos los documentos filtrados de tal manera que coincida el campo a filtrar con alguno de los valores de la lista.

Lo primero que debemos hacer es obtener la lista de valores que deseamos filtrar:

```js
let data = [
  {id: 1, tipo_doc: 'DNI', doc: '12345678W'},
  {id: 2, tipo_doc: 'DNI', doc: '12345678X'},
  {id: 3, tipo_doc: 'DNI', doc: '12345678Y'},
  {id: 4, tipo_doc: 'DNI', doc: '12345678Z'}
];

let docs = data.map(doc => doc.doc);

console.log(docs);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Teniendo ya la lista de documentos (`docs`), podemos usar una simple consulta [`find`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) usando el operador `$in`, por ejemplo:

```js
db.asignaciones.find({ doc: { $in: docs } }, {_id: 0, tipoid: 1, doc: 1});
```

La consulta anterior devuelve una lista con el siguiente formato:

```js
[
    {
        tipoid: <valor>,
        doc: <valor>
    },
    ...
]
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo funcional del operador `$in` en el [siguiente Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2nXYwuud9NZ).

Suponiendo que esta consulta la realizas usando [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/), la misma la puedes realizar sobre el modelo de datos que enlaza a tu colección de asignaciones, por ejemplo:

```js
// obtenemos data:
let data = await DB.sequelize.query(querys.get_ges_dav(schemaName,[req.query.fecha_inicial,req.query.fecha_final],req.query.unidad));
data = data[0] || [];

// obtenemos docs:
let docs = data.map(doc => doc.doc);

// obtenemos los tipos de documentos:
let tipos = await Asignacion.find({doc: {$in: docs}}, {_id: 0, tipoid: 1, doc: 1}).exec();
```

Una vez que en una sola consulta hemos obtenido los documentos que necesitamos podemos actualizar el valor de `data`. Para ello usamos métodos propios de `Array`. Por ejemplo:

```js
let data = [
  {id: 1, tipo_doc: 'DNI', doc: '12345678W'},
  {id: 2, tipo_doc: 'DNI', doc: '12345678X'},
  {id: 3, tipo_doc: 'DNI', doc: '12345678Y'},
  {id: 4, tipo_doc: 'DNI', doc: '12345678Z'}
];

console.log('Antes:');
console.log(data);

let tipos = [
  {tipoid: 'DNI', doc: '12345678W'},
  {tipoid: 'NIF', doc: '12345678X'},
  {tipoid: 'PASAPORTE', doc: '12345678Y'},
  {tipoid: 'NIE', doc: '12345678Z'}
];

data = data.map(doc => {
  let tipo = tipos.find(el => el.doc === doc.doc);
  doc.tipo_doc = tipo.tipoid;
  return doc;
});

console.log('Después:');
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

En este caso hemos usado el método [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), que devuelve el primer elemento de la lista que coincide con la comparación aportada.

Obviamente, debemos tomar en cuenta el caso en que los documentos devueltos de MongoDB sean menor en cantidad a los elementos pasados en la lista. Para ello podríamos devolver el valor actual del elemento en `data`, por ejemplo:

```js
let data = [
  {id: 1, tipo_doc: 'DNI', doc: '12345678W'},
  {id: 2, tipo_doc: 'DNI', doc: '12345678X'},
  {id: 3, tipo_doc: 'DNI', doc: '12345678Y'},
  {id: 4, tipo_doc: 'DNI', doc: '12345678Z'}
];

console.log('Antes:');
console.log(data);

// Hay menos tipos que los buscados originalmente
let tipos = [
  {tipoid: 'DNI', doc: '12345678W'},
  {tipoid: 'NIF', doc: '12345678X'},
  {tipoid: 'PASAPORTE', doc: '12345678Y'}
];

data = data.map(doc => {
  let tipo = tipos.find(el => el.doc === doc.doc);
  // sólo si hay un elemento coincidente:
  if(tipo && tipo.tipoid) {
    doc.tipo_doc = tipo.tipoid;
  }
  return doc;
});

console.log('Después:');
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: La mejor respuesta!!!

Te cuento que lo aplique y el único inconveniente que tengo es que la variable de data no me esta llegando en fotmato json sino en el siguiente (y no me premite hacer el reeemplazo):

{,
    codigo: 'LL  ',,
    tipo_id: '99',,
    deudor_id: '000000000433644',,
    fecha_gestion: '20210708',,
    hora_gestion: '163503',    
  },,
  {,
    codigo: 'LL  ',,
    tipo_id: '99',,
    deudor_id: '000000000437190',,
    fecha_gestion: '20210708',,
    hora_gestion: '154033',   
  },,

Comment: No lo entiendo, `data` es una respuesta de `sequelize`, por lo tanto debería ser una lista de objetos de Javascript (no hay JSON allí) ¿o me estoy perdiendo algo?

Comment: Si en cambio recibes una cadena JSON, la misma parece mal formada. Se me ocurren un par de trucos para corregirla pero eso estaría fuera del alcance de la pregunta actual. Te sugiero que hagas la pregunta en el sitio. Saludos

Comment: Agregue una actualización a la pregunta, para ver si me puedes ayuda. Estoy a una hora de que me saquen, no sabes lo mucho que me estas salvando.